# Cambiar texto de boton js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy realizando un proyecto de registrer y login en js. Y estoy usando localStorage. Mi itencion es que cuando el usuario ingresa, te redirecciona al index, y el boton que antes se llamaba 'acceso a tu cuenta' Pase a llamarse el nombre del usuario que ingreso.
Eso es lo que no estoy pudieron lograr. Voy a compartir el codigo para que pueda ser mas claro.

Codigo .js

```
const loginForm = document.querySelector('#loginForm')
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const nombreLogin = document.querySelector('#namelogin').value
    const passwordLogin = document.querySelector('#passlogin').value

    const Users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || []
    const validUser = Users.find(user => user.name === nombreLogin && user.pass === passwordLogin)
    if(!validUser){
        return alert('Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos!')
    }
    alert(`Bienvenido ${validUser.name}`)
    localStorage.setItem('login_success', JSON.stringify(validUser))
    window.location.href = 'index.html'

})
```

Y luego en el index:

```
<script>
    const nombreUsuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_success'))
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_success')) || false
    const nameusuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('validUser'))
    if(user){
        const botonLogin = document.getElementById('accesoUsuario')
        this.textContent = `${validUser.name}`;
    }
</script>
```

Soy relativamente nuevo en JS. Y voy integrango partes de distintas fuentes. Puede que no este del todo optimizado el codigo. Pero funciona.
Aclaro que es solo para uso totalmente academico y practica personal. No es para trabajo ni puesta en produccion.

Asi que cualquier comentario es de total utilidad.

Gracias!!

---

Pude resolverlo, y elijo no borrar el post por si a alguien le sirve.
Como quedo modificado el codigo .js

```
localStorage.setItem('login_success', JSON.stringify(validUser.name))
```

Y el index:

```
const nombreUsuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_success'))
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_success')) || false
    const botonLogin = document.getElementById('accesoUsuario')
    if(user){
        botonLogin.innerHTML = nombreUsuario.name
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podría por favor proporcionar el HTML para que todos puedan replicarlo individualmente y tener la misma visión de tu proyecto y encontrar una solución que se adapte mejor?

Comment: En lugar de responder en tu pregunta, considera borrar esa respuesta y añadirla como respuesta real, así de paso te ganas unos puntitos.